# How would you substitute MBProgressHud loading view in for PFQueryTableViewController's stock loading view?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mbprogresshud

Parse.com has a stock loading `view` for their `PFQueryTVC`. However, I want to customize it and implement the style of `MBProgressHUD's` loading view. Has anyone accomplished this or something similar, and have any tips to share?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find a subview that is the loading view, then remove it and put an MBProgressHUD in its place. Code:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview class] == NSClassFromString(@"PFLoadingView"))
        {
            // find the loading label and loading activity indicator inside the PFLoadingView subviews
            for (UIView *loadingViewSubview in subview.subviews) {
                if ([loadingViewSubview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                {
                    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)loadingViewSubview;
                    //code to remove and put in new view.
                }

                if ([loadingViewSubview isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]])
                {
                    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)loadingViewSubview;
                    //code to remove and put in new view.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Credit for the for loop here: https://gist.github.com/chrisvoss/3416639